# How would I map a JSON structure via TypeScript or JavaScript to reformat and remove some unwanted elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have a response from a database (DynamoDB) that adds M and SS. I want just a clean structure.  What's the easiest way to map this out?

Input

`[{"M":{"usernameFormatOptionsCreate":{"SS":["sms"]}}},{"M":{"UsernameFormatOptionsChange":{"SS":["sms"]}}}]`

Expected Output

`[ { "usernameFormatOptionsCreate": ["sms"] },
{ "usernameFormatOptionsChange": ["sms"] }]`

Comment: Array.prototype.filter / map

Comment: yes, that is what I was using but couldn't quite figure out the correct syntax without doing an ugly for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` and `Object.values` for get first key and value like below

```js
let arr = [{"M": {"usernameFormatOptionsCreate": {"SS": ["sms"]}}}, {"M": {"UsernameFormatOptionsChange": {"SS": ["sms"]}}}];
let output = arr.map(function(c){
  let key = Object.keys(c.M)[0];
  let value = Object.values(c.M[key])[0];
  let result = {};
  result[key] = value;
  return result;
});
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = [{"M": {"usernameFormatOptionsCreate": {"SS": ["sms"]}}}, {"M": {"UsernameFormatOptionsChange": {"SS": ["sms"]}}}];
let output = input.map(({M}) => {
  let y = {};
  Object.entries(M).forEach(([key, {SS}]) => {
    y[key] = SS;
  });
  return y;
});

console.log(output);
```